# Correct MIME type for returning JSON entity

Tags: json, mime-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The *right* JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)

I am using Java for the server side programming, and I want to return JSON data from the server side. I have come across the several return formats of JSON as below

```
application/json
text/javascript
text/x-json
application/x-javascript
text/x-javascript
```

Out of which, according to the standard, what should be used as the correct format of the MIME type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), which is the industry standard for the MIME types of JSON, says that the currect format of the JSON response MIME type should be `application/json`.

Comment: +1 for the RFC citation.

Comment: Thanks bro for the quick response, excellent answer BTW

Comment: Great conversation you have there